# Problems installing drush on fresh install of Ubuntu

Tags: bashrc, installed-programs

Hi I installed Ubuntu earlier today and have only just installed Apache, PHP 5, Mysql and PHPMyadmin.

I followed [these directions](http://docs.drush.org/en/master/install-alternative/).

So I installed composer globally like so:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

I then added THIS to my `.bashrc` file:

```
PATH="$HOME/.composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"
```

That all seemed to work fine and I can run composer from anywhere on my computer.

Then I installed drush like so:

```
Composer global require drush/drush:8.*
```

That all seemed to install fine. But then I ran '`drush status`' to see how it was doing and I got the following:

```
The program 'drush' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install drush
```

I KNOW that won't work. If I install drush that way it installs drush 5 (and I can't update it to the current version).

Um, so what the heck did I do wrong?

Comment: Where does Drush get installed?

Comment: Hard to say. I found this:  /home/user/.config/composer/vendor/drush/drush/drush...there are a bunch of files in this folder including drush.bat, drush.php, etc. However even if I run drush from this folder it doesn't recognize the command.

Comment: Look at the `~/.composer` folder to find drush

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the problem. The issue was the path I put into my .bashrc file. I didn't actually have a .composer file, despite what the directions I was using indicated. I had a .config file though! Once I changed the path in my .bashrc to reflect that (ie. PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH" and restarted my terminal it worked.

Comment: Great! This worked by adding `export PATH="$HOME/.config/composer/vendor/bin:$PATH"` in `~/.bashrc`